# how can I know if a web api is supported by WKWebView?

Tags: webview, mobile-safari, wkwebview, webapi

I am a web frontend developer and working on buildiing webview pages in hybrid app for the first time.

I was considering [Page Visibility API](https://developer.mozilla.org/ko/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API) and trying to find out if it is supported by webview browsers, like WKWebView and Android Webview, and couldn't find informations about WKWebView support.

I know there is a `safari on iOS` tab in [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/?search=page%20visibility), but I am not sure if it means WKWebView supports the same.

so I want to know

- if `safari on iOS` supports something, does it mean WKWebView supports the same?
- if not, where can I find informations about WKWebView support?

thank you in advance.